# YAML Intersect of Multiple lists

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
    "tag_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {"vm_list": ["NSY6TFSANSBL01"]},
            {"vm_list": ["NSY6TFSANSBL01", "NSY6TFSANSBL02"]},
            {"vm_list": ["NSY6TFSANSBL01", "NSY6TFSANSBL02", "NSY6TFSANSBL03"]}
        ]
    }
```

I need to find the intersection of multiple lists.

I know that intersect of 2 lists is like this

```yaml
- set_fact:
    final_list: "{{ tag_info.results[0].vm_list | intersect(tag_info.results[1].vm_list) }}"
```

I need the same for N number of lists. Could someone help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tasks below do the job

```
   - set_fact:
        final_list: "{{ final_list|default([]) + [
                        tag_info.results[item].vm_list|
                        intersect(tag_info.results[item + 1].vm_list)] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, tag_info.results|length - 1, 1)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: final_list
```

give

```
    "final_list": [
        [
            "NSY6TFSANSBL01"
        ], 
        [
            "NSY6TFSANSBL01", 
            "NSY6TFSANSBL02"
        ]
    ]
```

---

Fixed data

```
    tag_info:
      changed: false
      msg: "All items completed"
      results:
        - {"vm_list": ["NSY6TFSANSBL01"]}
        - {"vm_list": ["NSY6TFSANSBL01", "NSY6TFSANSBL02"]}
        - {"vm_list": ["NSY6TFSANSBL01", "NSY6TFSANSBL02", "NSY6TFSANSBL03"]}
```

---

> Q: *"Intersection of all the lists under tag_info.results can be N Number of vm_list objects."*

A: Start with the first `vm_list` object and instead of addition *intersect* next `vm_list` objects. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        final_list: "{{ final_list|
                        default(tag_info.results.0.vm_list)|
                        intersect(tag_info.results[item].vm_list) }}"
      loop: "{{ range(1, tag_info.results|length, 1)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: final_list
```

give

```
    "final_list": [
        "NSY6TFSANSBL01"
    ]
```